# How to Combine 2 integer columns in a dataframe and keep the type as integer itself in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 columns df[year] and df[month]. It has values ranging from 2000 to 2017 and month values 1 - 12.

How to combine these to another column which would contain the combined output.

Eg:

```
Year   Month   Y0M
2000    1   200001
2000    2   200002
2000    3   200003
2000    10  200010
```

Note : there is a 0 added in between Year and Month in Y0M column, (only for single digit numbers and not double digit)

Currently I am able to only do this by converting to string, but I want to retain them as type numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternative solution:

```
In [11]: df['Y0M'] = df[['Year','Month']].dot([100,1])

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
   Year  Month     Y0M
0  2000      1  200001
1  2000      2  200002
2  2000      3  200003
3  2000     10  200010
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like `df[year] * 100 + df[month]` would help.